# Windows VPN not working with extensive routing?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I have set up a windows server 2012 VPN service, which works like a charm within my network. Thing is, I have an external IP which is routed to one on my local network. All the traffic should be going through this accordingly.

It looks like this:

```
212.xx.xx.xx--> 192.168.xx.xx   --> 10.xx.xx.xx
External IP --> Gateway (IpCop) --> My Server
```

However, when I connect to my external IP using the windows built-in VPN client, it gets as far as asking my credentials but then it always fails to establish a tunnel. If I directly connect to my gateway (192.168.xx.xx) it just works.

Any ideas? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get in your VPN client?

Comment: It tells me that no tunnel could be established is all. It's on "connecting" for ages after verifying my sign-in info. Then this happens: (screenshot) https://gyazo.com/a36459c49983ace6acfa7a98b7447f87

Comment: As I said, the connection is PPTP so the IPSec stuff in the error message is pretty useless IMO.

Comment: What do you mean by it just works? Is the gateway able to ping/connect to your server? As one is in 192.168.x. and on is in the 10.x.x.x network you'd need some kind of routing between those two.

Comment: Yes, required ports and such are forwarded from my gateway directly to my server. It's using IPCop's forwarding feature. The gateway can ping everything, the server can ping everything, and I can connect to the gateway through the external IP (212.xx.xx.xx) - just the VPN does not work if I try to establish it over the external IP.

Comment: However it (the vpn) does work if I use the gateway's IP directly. It establishes a tunnel like you would expect.

Comment: But IPCop would be a Linux machine that doesn't have an endpoint for your VPN? Could it be that you're using some form of NAT and you're just forwarding any traffic to your server?

Comment: It's like this, our gateway (which isn't managed by me) forwards any traffic coming to the 212.xx.xx.xx address to the 192.168.xx.xx address. The 192.168.xx.xx address forwards the ports for PPTP (47 GRE, 1738 TCP iirc) to the windows server. Maybe it's that extra layer that has windows confused? As I said, the VPN works when I connect to the 192.168.xx.xx (it also works when I directly connect to the server, naturally).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47064/discussion-between-eskir-and-seth).